# Mysql - I want to get default null column when nothing match to 'in clause'

Tags: mysql

Test_table

| name | job |
| --- | --- |
| steve | artist |
| john | programmer |

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_table IN ('steve', 'anna');
```

What I want

| name | job |
| --- | --- |
| steve | artist |
| anna | null |

How can I get this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to maintain a separate table containing all the names you want to appear in your report.  Sans a bona fide table, we can use an inline query.  Then, left join to your table above to get the result you want:

```sql
SELECT t1.name, t2.job
FROM
(
    SELECT 'steve' AS name UNION ALL
    SELECT 'anna'
) t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.name = t2.name;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.
However, hmm.. what if I don't know what's not in my table?? (for example, steve or anna, anything can be not in the table)

Comment: or I have several more names to join(ex, kate, sally, brown, josh)

Comment: SQL doesn't work this way.  It performs operations on a table or bunch of tables.

Comment: Oh I just got answer!

SELECT t1.name, t2.job
FROM
(  
    SELECT 'josh' AS name UNION ALL
    SELECT 'steve' AS name UNION ALL
    SELECT 'anna'
) t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.name = t2.name;

Comment: ref_table(which contain set of names) and use_table(which contain name and job) is  on the seperated mysql server and it transmit the data by using json type.

It's the primitive problem 